# How to make this plugin compatible with socket.io 0.8

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I had used this plugin in my first version https://github.com/saschagehlich/node-socket.io-client/ now i am upgrading my socket.io 0.6 to 0.8 , this module is not compatible with socket.io 0.8 ,

So how can i upgrade this module for compatible with socket.io 0.8.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead you use the official [Socket.IO-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client), which is even used by Socket.IO internally. It will be always updated with the latest version of Socket.IO.

Edit: It seems Socket.IO-client doesn't work if the Node version is above 0.4.12.

Comment: i want to use it as browser simulated client in node.js , i tried using this and it has given me an error .  https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/694

Comment: I've used that for the same purpose and it worked, look at my code: http://pastie.org/3050848

Comment: okay , when i tried and it is giving me an error as described in above link of github , at top of my client file is this /*! Socket.IO.js build:0.8.7, development. Copyright(c) 2011 LearnBoost <dev@learnboost.com> MIT Licensed */ what is in your file

Comment: please post ur file of socket.io client  here .

Comment: client version and sever version should match

Comment: @WebDev it seems Socket.IO-client doesn't work on the server anymore for node > 0.4.12. `3rdEden (Socket.io dev) confirmed.

Comment: I downgrade my node to 0.4.11 , but it is still giving the same error .